# JQuery effect is applied only to 1st element

Tags: jquery, html

i have coded this simple script (i am learning now Javascript & JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#lnkCollapse").click(function () {
        $("#contentArea").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

in my page i have some tags A href that i have added the id=lnkCollapse.

```
<a  id="lnkCollapse" href="#" class="circle">
     <h3>Some title</h3>
</a>
```

The problem is that this script is applied only to the 1st a href in the html and not in the others.. why is that? Also, if i change the position of the id="lnkCollapse"

```
<a   href="#" class="circle" id="lnkCollapse">
     <h3>Some title</h3>
</a>
```

the script isnt applied at all. thanks a lot!

Comment: Its not about changing the position of ID.ID is unique and can be used to refer one item in a webpage..To refer multiple times have to use class.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about duplicate ID's, again !

Comment: @adeneo if i knew which was the exact problem, i would write the proper title or i would search it in google to find it.

Comment: That's not a problem, feel free to ask anything you like, but when a question is about a silly typo, not being able to type valid markup or has been asked a few thousand times before, it's not very useful for the community and should be closed. It's really not your fault for asking for help, but more our responsibility to close off-topic questions.

Comment: ok you have right but for me, that i am learning now javascript basic erros cannot be avoided.. anyway.. thx for the guys who answered my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Only one element can have a given id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id). Use a class instead of an id :

```
<a href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse">
     <h3>Some title</h3>
</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lnkCollapse").click(function () {
        $("#contentArea").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

let me guess... you have multiple elements `<a>` with same id.. **id should always be unique**.. use class instead.. change your `<a>` id to class and use `.` operator.

```
 <a  class="lnkCollapse" href="#" class="circle"> 
 //--^^^^^---here

 $(".lnkCollapse").click(function () {
 //-^--here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML

```
<a   href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse" id="lnkCollapse1">
 <h3>Some title</h3>
</a>

<a  id="lnkCollapse2" href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse">
 <h3>Some title</h3>
</a>
```

Use this javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".lnkCollapse").click(function () {
    $("#contentArea").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
    });
});
```